# Is prefix sum included in dynamic programming?

Tags: list, dynamic-programming, cumulative-sum, prefix-sum

I've been solving algorithm problems, and I'm a bit confused about the terms.

When we want to calculate prefix sum (or cumulative sum) like the code below, can we say that we are using dynamic programming?

```
def calc_prefix_sum(nums):
    N = len(nums)
    prefix_sum = [0] * (N + 1)
    for i in range(1, N + 1):
        prefix_sum[i] = prefix_sum[i - 1] + nums[i - 1]
    return prefix_sum

nums = [1, 3, 0, -2, 1]
print(calc_prefix_sum(nums))
```

```
[0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3]
```

According to the definition in this [page](https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-dynamic-programming-patterns-for-coding-interviews/m2G1pAq0OO0),

> Dynamic programming is used where we have problems, which can be
> divided into similar sub-problems so that their results can be
> re-used.

In my prefix_sum algorithm, the current calculation (prefix_sum[i]) is divided into similar sub-problems (prefix_sum[i - 1] + nums[i - 1]) so that the previous result (prefix_sum[i - 1]) can be re-used. So I am assuming that calculating prefix sum is one of  the applications of dynamic programming.

Can I say it's dynamic programming, or should I use different terms? (Especially, I am thinking about the situation in coding interviews.)

Answer (score 5):

No, the correct term is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), not dynamic programming. Dynamic programming requires the problem to have [optimal substructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure) as well as [overlapping subproblems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems). Prefix sum has optimal substructure but it does not have overlapping subproblems. Therefore, this optimization should be called memoization.

Comment: Agreed with @Yash more on this DP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, prefix sums can be considered as a form of Dynamic Programming. It is the simplest way to calculate the sum of a range given a static array by using a prefix array which stores data based on previous sums.

Prefix Sum Array Construction Runtime = O(n) 
Prefix Sum Query Runtime = O(1)

Answer (score 0):

People often say that Kadane's algorithm is DP, and Kadane's is only 1 if statement away from a prefix sum.

```py
def maxSubArray(nums: List[int]) -> int:
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i-1] > 0:
            nums[i] = nums[i-1] + nums[i]
    return max(nums)
```

If you tried to calculate a prefix sum recursively, you would end up with an O(n^2) without memoization but an O(n) algorithm with memoization. This is because of overlapping subproblems.

```py
nums = [1, 3, 0, -2, 1]
def cumsum(i):
    if i < 0:
        return 0
    return nums[i] + cumsum(i-1)
prefix_sum = [cumsum(i) for i in range(len(nums))]
```

We can see that `cumsum(0)` is called 5 times, since the recursion must hit the base case before returning, and we call the function 5 times. `cumsum(1)` is called 4 times, `cumsum(2)` is called 3 times, and so on.

This is why I would say that prefix sum has both optimal substructure and overlapping subproblems.